# MySQL Update one row

Tags: mysql

I want to update a row from one table to another

I am trying something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ps_product_shop (id_category_default)
SELECT Distinct id_category_default
FROM ps_product
WHERE id_product BETWEEN 1 AND 6226
```

But I get primary key error
I need to change values from ps_product to ps_product_shop for the id_category_default

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?  Your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: I mees up something, but the thing is that I have two tables that need to have same data, but in ps_product_shop in id_category_default row is wrong data so I need to copy data from ps_product to correct it.

Comment: All tables have same id_product

ps_product
id_product  id_category_default
213   333

ps_product_shop
id_product  id_category_default
213  444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
UPDATE ps_product_shop prod_shop
INNER JOIN ps_product prod USING(id_product)
SET prod_shop.id_category_default = prod.id_category_default
WHERE prod_shop.id_product BETWEEN 1 AND 6226
```